# Issue with handling listcontrol column header checkbox click?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am currently working on propertysheet and in that my second page consists of a listcontrol .I have added checkbox to the column header and set the listcontrol with LVS_EX_CHECKBOX style.So,now the very first most column and its header consists of checkboxes.

when I check the checkboxes corresponding to the items one by one ,and when I am checking  the last item checkbox of the list then the header checkbox is also getting checked.Till this point it's fine .Now I unselected all the checkboxes and now tried click the header checkbox to set the check state for all the items checkboxes.Unfortunately I am not able to get the list items checkboxes checked.Only that header checkbox is getting checked and unchecked.

Adding checkbox to the listheader in the following way in the page class.

```
BOOL OnInitDialog()
{
DWORD dwStyle = ::GetWindowLong(header, GWL_STYLE);
dwStyle |= HDS_CHECKBOXES;
::SetWindowLong(header, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);

m_listCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(m_listCtrl.GetExtendedStyle() |
                            LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

}
```

I tried handling the following events for getting the column header checkbox click

```
HDN_ITEMCLICK

HDN_ITEMSTATEICONCLICK
```

//This is implemented in LVN_ITEMCHANGED event handler (When checking list items checkbox one by one and for the final check in the list I am setting header checkbox).

```
void CMFPSearchListView::OnListViewItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
LVCOLUMN pColumn = {0};
pColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
m_listCtrl.GetColumn(0, &pColumn);
if(blAllChecked)
    pColumn.fmt |= HDF_CHECKED;
else
    pColumn.fmt &= ~HDF_CHECKED;


//m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, &pColumn);
m_listCtrl.SetColumn(0, &pColumn);
*pResult=0;    
}
```

Can anyone please let me know if I am not triggering the right event .
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `HDN_ITEMSTATEICONCLICK` message you need to handle.

```
ON_NOTIFY(HDN_ITEMSTATEICONCLICK, 0, &CMFPSearchListView::OnHdnItemStateIconClickListctrl)
```

Handler code:

```
void CMFPSearchListView::OnHdnItemStateIconClickListctrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMHEADER pNMHeader = (LPNMHEADER)pNMHDR;

    // first determine whether the click was a checkbox change
    if (pNMHeader->pitem->mask & HDI_FORMAT && pNMHeader->pitem->fmt & HDF_CHECKBOX)
    {
        // now determine whether it was checked or unchecked
        BOOL bUnChecked = pNMHeader->pitem->fmt & HDF_CHECKED;

        // apply check state to each list item
        for (int nItem = 0; nItem < m_listCtrl.GetItemCount(); nItem++)
            m_listCtrl.SetCheck(nItem, !bUnChecked);
    }

    *pResult = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.When I did as you suggested ,when I am checking the header checkbox then all the items are getting checked but entire items in the list are coming to the selection mode (blue color selection to all the items in the list).How can we avoid that selection when we select the header checkbox only the items should get selected right?Before this selection is not coming .After I did as you suggested,is this because of any style settings to be done?

Comment: Actually the listcontrol is set to the following style.         m_listCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(m_listCtrl.GetExtendedStyle() |LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT); should I change the listcontrol style?

Comment: All items being selected is the default CListCtrl behaviour when returning with `pResult = 0;`

Comment: can't we avoid that selection?

Comment: Resolved the issue.Just set pResult = 1; made me to get rid of that selection .Thanks for your valuable suggestions and help :)